# on register, check if username exists -- capitalization problem

Tags: php, mysql, case-sensitive

My homefried account registration system proceeds thusly:

1. complete registration form
2. check if username already exists - reject/pass
3. copy data to temp user table, send confirmation email
4. upon using link in confirmation email, copy data from temp to active user table

The other day a user emailed me to say he was getting the error message "Could not create user."

I couldn't recall ever hearing that, so I dug into my registration code and that error pops out if the query to insert the temp data into the active user table fails.

It failed because his username, which has a unique index in the table, already existed in the active user table... but he had passed the initial existing username check...?

Turned out the name he had tried to register was "User" but there was already a "user" -- so case-insensitivity is coming into play.

Does username exist? query string:

```
SELECT username FROM user_basic_data WHERE username='$cleanTempUsername'
```

Confirmed, now insert into active table string:

```
INSERT INTO user_basic_data (username, ...) VALUES ('$activeUsername', ...)
```

So the case-sensitivity apparently applies when I run a select statement ("User" != "user") but does not apply when I run an insert.

Capitalization is important to many users, so what's my fix of least resistance from here?

Answer (score 0):

Best move would probably be to use a case-sensitive collation for your tables.

Maybe try `latin1_bin` or `utf8_bin`.

Comment: Would changing collation now affect my data? Or is that a not-sure, test-and-check kind of thing?

Comment: It should automatically convert the data to the new collation without altering it. The only time you'd run into problems is if you're switching from case-sensetive to -insensetive.

Answer (score 0):

if you want case sensitive usernames use a varbinary datatype...

```
create table users
(
user_id int unsigned not null auto_increment primary key,
username varbinary(32) unique not null,
...
)
engine=innodb;

insert into users (username) values ('foo'),('Foo'),('FOO');
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do php strtolower() or mysql LOWER() to make the input a lowercase name regardless of the input. That way they can use whatever case they want but the database always deals with lowercase usernames. Of course, it means you can only have one username with the name 'user', but it does solve the case insensitivity problem and allow the users to type whatever case they want for their username with just a single change. Just don't do that with the password.